# How do I stop my switch statement from outputting the case in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I am trying to write a function that can accomplish 3 tasks by using the menu statement in Matlab, But for some reason it keeps outputting the case number with my function answer.

```
    function fcn=jon2(x)

     fcn=menu('Choose a Function:','ceil','round','sign');

     switch fcn
       case 1
         ceil(x)
       case 2
         round(x)
       case 3
         sign(x)
     end
    end
```

when i input 12 and select round, the answers come out:

ans =

```
12
```

ans =

```
 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use the function properly, if you defined it as: `fcn=jon2(x)`
then you should write each output using it:

```
...
case 2
    fcn = round(x);
...
```

also, use `;` to suppress output to the command line...

Answer (score 1):

Though @natan has already found the critical point I would actually prevent assigning to your switch variable inside the case. I can imagine that could lead to some confusing debugging. Also it is considered good practice to always add an 'otherwise', what you would want to happen there is of course up to you. Here is what I would recommend:

```
function fcn=jon2(x)

yourChoice=menu('Choose a Function:','ceil','round','sign');

switch yourChoice
    case 1
        fcn = ceil(x);
    case 2
        fcn = round(x);
    case 3
        fcn = sign(x);
    otherwise
        error('Not all cases are handled')
end
end
```

Of course this would require you to call the function without semicolon if you want to output the result of the operation. Example:

```
myResult = jon2(10)
```